# replace text from list of dictionary python

Tags: python

I am trying to convert

```
list1=["{\"username\":\"abhi\",\"pass\":2087}"]
```

to

```
list1=[{"username":"abhi","pass":2087}]
```

Is there any way to do it without lots of splitting and creating dictionary and then putting into list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can parse it as a JSON string.

```
import json
list2 = [json.loads(item) for item in list1]
```

Output -

```
[{u'pass': 2087, u'username': u'abhi'}]
```